# How to apply DRM on a .mp3/.wav file

Tags: drm

Can anyone help me to apply DRM on .mp3 or .wav. I know about DRM, but i have no idea about it's implementation process. If anyone has any idea on DRM's implementation(for .mp3/.wav) pleae help me. It would be great if this is for C#. It would be nice if any of you give me some Source/link.

Thanks
Pranab

Comment: I don't think there is a free solution to do this. Someone please correct me if I'm wrong. You can checkout "Live DRM" though.

Comment: People don't accept music files with DRM anymore nowadays. So don't waste time and money on it.

Comment: check this article which i wrote recently : http://aameer.github.io/articles/digital-rights-management-multi-drm/  it explains in details about how to achieve multi-drm

Answer (score 3):

To DRM any sort of file, all you are really doing is encrypting it in such a way that only authorized clients (programs) can retrieve the content from the file. Typically, this requires special client software. Depending on your requirements, it may also require a central server for these clients to call back to.

In general, you cannot simple "DRM an .mp3", because a generic MP3 player cannot read the data then. (if it could, it wouldn't be a DRMed file then, now would it?)

Answer (score 2):

Possible, yes. Easy, not so much:

- The "easiest" way is to drop the MP3 or WAV requirement and go with WMA (Windows Media Audio). In that case, you could use the [Microsoft PlayReady Server SDK](https://wmlicense.smdisp.net/licenserequest-04/licenserequest.aspx) (expensive - several tens of thousand $) to do Windows Media DRM-compatible encryption. The resulting encrypted WMA can then be played by Windows Media Player and by a very large number of portable devices, after having received a "license" (essentially, decryption key + usage rights).
- If you decide to go with WMA and you can't do large upfront investments, perhaps a hosted (SaaS) solution such as [BuyDRM](http://www.buydrm.com) is for you.
- Another possibility, which requires an even larger investment, if you want to stick with MP3 or WAV, is to use PlayReady itself with the "Envelope" format, or [OMA 2 DRM](http://www.openmobilealliance.org/Technical/release_program/drm_v2_2.aspx) with the "DCF" format, or [Marlin DRM](http://www.marlin-community.com/), or several other ones, which in addition to investing on the server side would also require you to write a custom media player.

Comment: I know this old question , but I wonder if there any way to add small size of byte inside the container of mp3 file while broadcast it , so regular player can't read it as corrupted file while a customized player can remove the added bytes and decode it as regular mp3 file .

Comment: Sure, it is possible... but there's no DRM or any protection in there. This is basically security through obscurity. Once the first smart person manages to reverse-engineer the format, it's trivial for anyone to strip off the "protection" for _any_ similar file.

Comment: I know but I need it as fast cheap DRM method the player will be able to download decoding algorithm  that changed frequency e.g "each hour".